# Receiving UINavBar Items actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationitem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //So I created a NavBar Item in my detail view

    UIBarButtonItem * saveButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                    target:self            
                                                    action:@selector(saveFunc)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
}
```

I want to write some code to save the data when the user clicks the save button in the NavBar. How do I write the method for this. I am stuck I did it when I created a navBar item through interface builder but I am having troubles doing it when I create the button through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now just implement the method

> -(void) saveFunc

and dont forget to add:

> [saveButton release];

Comment: Thanks so much, Silly me was putting IBAction instead of void

Comment: IBAction is synonymous with void, so there was probably some other reason.